# Most efficient way of checking idle users on linux captive portal?

Tags: iptables, linux, captive-portal

I am building a basic captive portal script, with support for idle timeout. I managed to create iptables rules on authentication in the browser.

However, I'm not sure how to detect users that are active, and users that are idle for a certain amount of time. e.g When a user is not active for 30 minutes, he needs to be logged out.

What could be a good way to know if a user is idle?

Answer (score -2):

You can check out the inactivity time (idle time) with command `w -hfs` along with a bunch of other info.

Comment: This command shows the activity of users logged in on the local system, however captive portals don't use local logins. A user is just connected by the network.